# Routing 404 but it shows up on every page React js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Im trying to use 404 page, in this case it's called ErrorPage, but it will still show up on every page, how to fix this problem, can sb help me. I have tried to playaround with Switch but nothing seems to be working

render() {
let fullWidthPanel = ;

```
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {/* routes without a header & footer */}
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/register/confirm"
            component={AccountConfirm}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/drafts/draft-panel"
            component={() => fullWidthPanel}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/drafts/draft-panel/locations"
            component={Locations}
          />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          {/* Offer confirm page */}
          <Route exact path="/d/:slug" component={SharedOffer} />
          <Fragment>
            <Header />
            <Alerts />
            <div className="container body pb-5">
              {/* Any routes we want to protect, get PrivateRoute instead of Route */}
              {/* Auth and user related */}

              {/* General public routes */}
              <Route exact path="/blog" />

              <Route exact path="/" component={FrontPage} />
              {/* (Agency) Clients */}
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/clients" component={Clients} />
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path="/clients/edit"
                component={ClientsPanel}
              />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/drafts" component={Drafts} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/offers" component={Offers} />
              {/* Account management  */}
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/teams" component={Teams} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/discounts" component={Discounts} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="*" component={ErrorPage} />
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </Fragment>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AlertProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

}
}

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById("app"));

Answer (score -1):

don't use path for error page maybe it work I did not try it but maybe help you

Comment: tried it but still same error